# Word textbox in Excel worksheet

Tags: excel

We use Excel frequently to make documents, so that the info can be changed easily across other sheets.
Sheet 1 contains a Word textbox with a list of people on different shifts.  When the info in the textbox changes, is there a way to get the info in the textbox to change on other Sheets linked to sheet 1

Comment: An `ActiveX` text box?  i.e. If you select the text box it says something like `=EMBED("Forms.TextBox.1","")` in the formula bar?  Or do you mean a listbox (as it contains a list of people) - in which case is it `ActiveX` (`=EMBED("Forms.ListBox.1","")` in formula bar) or a form control list box (right-click it and it will have `Assign Macro` as an option in the pop-up menu).

Comment: A Drop-down list (from data validation), then the other sheets can look at that cell...

Comment: I will check the worksheet and give more info